# Override favicon output

Tags: 7

Some of search engines (yandex in my case) want me to output favicon with type image/x-icon.

But drupal 7 outputs it without this type.
How could i override this through template.php or any other suggestion? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code in your `template.php` should do the job.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $favicon = theme_get_setting('favicon');
  $type = 'image/x-icon';
  drupal_add_html_head_link(array('rel' => 'shortcut icon', 'href' => drupal_strip_dangerous_protocols($favicon), 'type' => $type));
}
```

[image: Change image/type to image/x-icon]

Comment: Unfortunately it did nothing to the output of the favicon (i did cleared the cash). Thanks

Comment: I've just tested it and it works fine for me.  You have change MYTHEME to the name of your theme, yes?

Comment: Yes of course i did..

Comment: Hmm...you might want to try clearing your cache a couple more times, and the browser cache - the code definitely works.  What sub-theme are you using?

Comment: I am using selfbuilt html5 theme. Ok thank you for the answer i`ll be hoping it will change someday )

Answer (score 5):

To alter or remove the favicon URL Drupal 7 points to by default (not just add another favicon link) try this:

```
function YOURTHEME_html_head_alter(&$head_elements)
{
  // Search the head elements for the Favicon
  foreach ($head_elements as $key => $element) {
    if (!empty($element['#attributes'])) {
      if (array_key_exists('href', $element['#attributes'])) {
        if (strpos($element['#attributes']['href'], 'misc/favicon.ico') > 0) 
        {
          // Change the URL
          $head_elements[$key]['#attributes']['href'] = '/'.drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOURTHEME').'/path/to/favicon.ico';

          // Or, delete the favicon link entirely
          unset($head_elements[$key]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another Simple Solution to this problem would be using a contributed module https://drupal.org/project/favicon.

Using this module, you can avoid getting 404 on those browsers which make a call to <>/favicon.ico to retrieve sites fav ICON. This behavior will cause a 404 Entry to show up in drupal logs.

Answer (score 1):

In **Drupal 8** you could use the following to remove the Icon Link (Don't remove the favicon.ico itself) as a [Link is depreciated](http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_ico_not_declared).

in the file: *themes/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_THEME.theme*

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 *
 * Search the head elements for the Favicon and remove it.
 * See: http://realfavicongenerator.net/faq#why_ico_not_declared.
 */
function YOUR_THEME_page_attachments_alter(&$page) {
  foreach ($page['#attached'] as $key => $element) {
    if ($key === 'html_head_link' && !empty($element)) {
      foreach ($element as $k => $item) {
        if (isset($item[0]['rel']) && $item[0]['rel'] === 'shortcut icon') {
          unset($page['#attached']['html_head_link'][$k]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What would you recommend to add all the different favicon-files to Drupal? Just putting them in the html.html.twig or is there a better way?

Comment: You may have a look on Drupal Metatag module. Personally I mostly ended up adding icons to html.html.twig, as the are static part of the theme.